# How to get Excel to recognise dates without a manual find and replace "/" for "/"?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find, sendkeys

How do I get excel to recognize timestamps as timestamps rather than strings?

If I do a find and replace on "/" with "/" it fixes it on most files:

```
Cells.Replace What:="/", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I have a chunk of code that checks if it's still in the wrong format by converting to "Comma" format and checking if the cell contains any "/" characters, then a break line that triggers in that instance to alert me that I need to manually do the find and replace on this file. If I stop the Macro when it fails and run it manually (Crtl+h, Enter), then it works and I can restart the macro to finish the standardisation. I need a way of automating this.

I have >2000 .csv files of a similar but not identical format. Each one contains ~350 variables, each with it's own timestamp and data column. I've written some code that formats it into a usable format. The original csv has the timestamps in "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss" format as is my computer and Excel default.

Excel seemingly randomly decides it can't recognise around a quarter of the files timestamps and instead interprets them as strings. This can be corrected by clicking into the cell and then clicking out of the cell, then excel recognises it as a timestamp. I need the timestamps recognised so that I can interpolate values into a standard sampling frequency as Excel can't interpolate using values it interprets as strings.

There are often well over 100k timestamps per file, so doing this manually isn't an option.

I've tried using SendKeys. The problem with that seems to be that it opens the find and replace dialogue for the VBA script editor, not for the excel sheet.
I've tried shifting focus before by calling:

```
Windows(windowname).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Application.SendKeys("^h")
```

I've also tried:

```
Windows(windowname).Application.SendKeys("^h")
```

Which both result in the find and replace being called on the VBA script editor.

I have no shortcut to start the Macro.

I've tried Matlab, but it can't deal with the header on the file or the columns populated with text. I'd like to retain all the data.

I have used the Macro recorder to record me doing the find and replace which results in:

```
Sub Fixer()
'
' Fixer Macro
'

'
    Selection.Replace What:="/", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

But this doesn't work when you run it on the same file.

I expect it to convert the string "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss" format into a date-time format that I can then convert into decimal format which I can then use for interpolating the values into a usable format. Instead I get no error message, and nothing happens.

An example line of date timestamps from the raw CSV is: 
"31/03/2019 14:55:57,1.0000000149,31/03/2019 14:55:57,14.6,31/03/2019 14:55:57,57.86,31/03/2019 14:55:57,0.175000000000068"

So the timestamp "31/03/2019 14:55:57" I want converting into "43555.62218750000"

I could use a script to deconstruct the string, calculate the decimal equivalent, and overwrite the cell, but this will take a prohibitively long time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried converting those strings to Doubles? Dates are numbers after all (the integer part would be a date, and the decimal part would be hours, minutes and seconds).

Comment: A trick which sometimes works is to add a column and set a formula to multiply the original column by 1.  This forces the text to be a number (which as stated above) is also a date.

Comment: first, excel is not doing anything 'randomly' and this is important to recognize.  Dates are not converting because your regional settings (probably) are set to MM/DD/YYYY .... -- and the example 31/03/2019 cannot be converted into such a date.  There is no month "31"  -- so be extremely wary of the dates that DID convert.  They probably look like 05/06/2019 -- and I bet you read in May 6, when that date ought to be June 5.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Good point, computers don't do things at random, I suppose I said "randomly" because I haven't been able to identify the cause yet. I've edited the question to clarify that the date formats are all aligned into "DD/MM/YYYY" format so that isn't the issue. I've verified this by checking a file with timestamps >12 DD, and it deals with it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First import the date/time field into Excel as ***Text***.  In my demo case I use column **A**.  Then run:

```
Sub TextToValue()
    Dim Kolumn As String, N As Long, i As Long
    Dim d As Double, dt As Date, tm As Date
    Dim v As Variant

    Kolumn = "A"
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, Kolumn).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, Kolumn).Text
        If InStr(1, v, "/") > 0 Then
            arr = Split(v, " ")
            brr = Split(arr(0), "/")
            dt = DateSerial(brr(2), brr(1), brr(0))
            tm = TimeValue(arr(1))
            d = CDbl(dt + tm)
            Cells(i, Kolumn).Clear
            Cells(i, Kolumn).Value = d
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

And after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to back up a step.

Your problem is common and is caused by **OPEN**ing a `csv` file where the date format (`DMY`) in this case is in a different format than your Windows Regional Setting on the your computer.

So even the input that appears to convert properly, will not be as the Day and Month will be exchanged from what you might expect.

Arguably the "best" fix for this issue, assuming you cannot alter the `csv` file, will be to **IMPORT** the file instead.

Depending on how you do the **IMPORT**, and that is Excel version dependent, you will have the opportunity, at the time of import, to define the date format of the incoming data, so it will be properly converted by Excel.

In `Power Query` you can specify to have `PQ` do the date conversion according to a specified locale.  In earlier versions of Excel, a Text-to-columns wizard will open allowing you to specify `DMY` for the format of the csv file.  I would suggest using `PQ` as it can easily handle the time portion, whereas with the older wizard you'll need to split the two, and then add them back together.